# How to set alias pattern of node's source alias?

Tags: 8, path-aliases, tokens

When I translate a node I want that node's path alias to be like it's source node's path alias.

So in the url pattern for the translation nodes I use the token:

> [node:source:url:path]

which [according to this thread should be fine](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2937775). But, it actually generates the alias "/node-402-0", although the source node has a path like "/welcome".

I have the feeling that in the token module the wrong language is being looked into.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you not simply build the URL the same way as in the source node, eg something like [node:source:title] if the source pattern is [node:title]?

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong its never just the title, unfortunately. i have a lot of different patterns for the original english nodes, since i have a lot of different content types. it would be nice to then just tell all translation to just copy the alias :(

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you can set the alias to not be translated in the the content language settings (Admin->Config->Regional->content language.

Under each content type there should be a url alias option. Unchecking this should make the alias the same for all languages.

Comment: unfortunately not. i do want some languages to have their own translated patterns, but some should not (like chinese shouldnt, but german should have own patterns)